# Delphi XE10.1 DataSnap Client Error "SetConnectTimeOut"

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I tried transfer of my Project from XE8 to XE10.1

DataSnap Client Module have SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection

When I set property `Driver.ConnectTimeout` to any value, then set `Connected=true`, I get error:

> "SetConnectTimeout"

Without any value in `Driver.ConnectTimeout` set connection is OK.

What my error?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. Embarcadero did.

In Delphi 10 Seattle (I don't have XE8), the implementation of the Data.DbxHTTPLayer.TDSHTTPNativeClient.SetConnectTimeout method is:

```
procedure TDSHTTPNativeClient.SetConnectTimeout(AMilisec: Integer);
begin
  FHTTP.ConnectTimeout := AMilisec;
end;
```

In Delphi 10.1 Berlin, the same method looks like this:

```
procedure TDSHTTPNativeClient.SetConnectTimeout(AMilisec: Integer);
begin

  raise ENotImplemented.Create('SetConnectTimeout');
end;
```

I edited the source (Data.DbxHTTPLayer.pas) to:

```
procedure TDSHTTPNativeClient.SetConnectTimeout(AMilisec: Integer);
begin
  FHTTPClient.ConnectionTimeout := AMilisec;
  //raise ENotImplemented.Create('SetConnectTimeout');
end;
```

And it solved the problem. The original .dcu and .o initially prevented the change from actually being linked into my app, so I added Data.DbxHTTPLayer.pas to my project (this was probably not the correct way to do it).

Comment: Why would Embarcadero do such a thing?

Comment: Between 10 and 10.1 they changed the underlying HTTP library.  My guess is they meant to come back to this and forgot.

Comment: Deserves to be reported as a Quality Portal issue.

Comment: I am having this problem in 10.1 update 2. I submitted a bug report here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16587